# ¿Hay alguna forma de permitir al usuario navegar por un directorio para seleccionar un archivo?

Tags: python, rutas

Basicamente, lo que quiero lograr es que el usuario pueda seleccionar un archivo de manera interactiva (como en el "examinar" de windows)

Comment: Esta  [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog) es lo mismo sólo que en inglés, échale un ojo.

Comment: Guille has tratado de realizar algo, tienes código para revisar?

Comment: Excelente, justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Existen librerias que pueden cubrir esta tarea, como [`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html).

Aquí un ejemplo sencillo de como implementarlo:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
archivo = askopenfilename()
```

Answer (score 1):

No sé si lo quieres hacer de forma gráfica o no, pero te digo como hacerlo en TUI:

```
import os

dirs = os.scandir(".") # «.» Hace referencia al directorio actual.
dirs = list(dirs) # dirs es un iterador, lo convertimos a una lista.

for x in range(len(dirs)):
    print(x, ".", dirs[x])

dir = int(input("\nSelecciona un directorio: "))

if dir < len(dirs):
    print("Has elegido:", dirs[dir])
```